# Plotting Coordinates over Raster

Tags: r, raster, point

this relates to the last question I asked (still a relative newbie to R, using RStudio, Version 1.2.5033). Basically, I have a raster file I downloaded online (NLCD 2016 land use) and I am wanting to plot shapefiles that delineate river basins and coordinates for sampling sites on top of the raster map. I am able to plot the shapefiles on top of the raster but for some reason I can not get the coordinates to plot on top. RStudio instead creates a new figure for the coordinates. Can anyone help solve this? Thanks!

Information about the raster (starts off in the code as nlcd and then gets reclassified and cropped to become rc):
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 7302, 11233, 82023366  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent     : 175185, 512175, 2386365, 2605425  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,-0,-0,-0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : /private/var/folders/f5/7wtm6gsn1qn70rxh1ny6m7m40000gn/T/RtmpRxBkDJ/raster/r_tmp_2020-05-28_090052_49820_66166.grd 
names      : NLCD_2016_Land_Cover_L48_20190424 
values     : 0, 90  (min, max)

Information about one of the shapefiles (9 total):
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 338204.4 ymin: 2456656 xmax: 350204.4 ymax: 2471206
CRS:            +proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,-0,-0,-0,0 +units=m +no_defs
                    Name                       geometry
1 WI20200528013216810000 POLYGON ((346454.4 2471206,...

Information about the Coordinates:
Simple feature collection with 9 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 213539 ymin: 2439512 xmax: 495172.2 ymax: 2577206
CRS:            +proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,-0,-0,-0,0 +units=m +no_defs

## A tibble: 9 x 2

Name                geometry
              
1 Allequash (495172.2 2577206)
2 Bassett   (214667.1 2447725)
3 Chippewa  (363545.1 2447006)
4 Como      (351253.3 2465617)
5 Flambeau  (374201.5 2501172)
6 Minnehaha (218719.3 2439788)
7 Red Cedar   (320474 2439512)
8 Shingle     (213539 2452466)
9 Trout     (341781.7 2464613)

Code:

```
All_Bas<-st_read("./Allequash/layers","globalwatershed")
Chip_Bas<-st_read("./Chippewa/layers","globalwatershed")
Bass_Bas<-st_read("./Bassett/layers","globalwatershed")
Como_Bas<-st_read("./Como/layers","globalwatershed")
Flam_Bas<-st_read("./Flambeau/layers","globalwatershed")
Minn_Bas<-st_read("./Minnehaha/layers","globalwatershed")
Red_Bas<-st_read("./Red Cedar/layers","globalwatershed")
Shin_Bas<-st_read("./Shingle/layers","globalwatershed")
Trout_Bas<-st_read("./Trout/layers","globalwatershed")

All_Bas_aea<-st_transform(All_Bas,crs(nlcd))
Chip_Bas_aea<-st_transform(Chip_Bas,crs(nlcd))
Bass_Bas_aea<-st_transform(Bass_Bas,crs(nlcd))
Como_Bas_aea<-st_transform(Como_Bas,crs(nlcd))
Flam_Bas_aea<-st_transform(Flam_Bas,crs(nlcd))
Minn_Bas_aea<-st_transform(Minn_Bas,crs(nlcd))
Red_Bas_aea<-st_transform(Red_Bas,crs(nlcd))
Shin_Bas_aea<-st_transform(Shin_Bas,crs(nlcd))
Trout_Bas_aea<-st_transform(Trout_Bas,crs(nlcd))

Basins<rbind(Chip_Bas_aea,Minn_Bas_aea,All_Bas_aea,Bass_Bas_aea,Como_Bas_aea,Flam_Bas_aea,Red_Bas_aea,Shin_Bas_aea,Trout_Bas_aea)
nlcd_crop<-crop(nlcd,Basins)

coordinates <-"Site Coordinates_degrees.xlsx"
site_coordinates<-read_excel(coordinates,sheet=1) #Proj=longlat datum=WGS84
rm(coordinates)
site_coordinates_crs<-CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

coordinates<st_as_sf(site_coordinates,coords=c("Longitude","Latitude"),crs=site_coordinates_crs)
coordinates_aes<-st_transform(coordinates,crs(nlcd))

m<-c(0,10,0,11,11,1,12,20,0,21,24,2,25,40,0,41,43,3,44,80,0,81,87,4,88,89,0,90,95,5)
rclmat<-matrix(m,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
rc<-reclassify(nlcd_crop,rclmat)
pal<-colorRampPalette(c("gray90","gray47","cornflowerblue","gray90","lightgreen","gray90","gray90","gray90","red","lightgreen"))

jpeg("Simplifed Landuse code.jpeg",width=1000,height=750)
plot(rc,col=pal(50),legend=FALSE)
plot(All_Bas_aea,color="white",lwd=2,fill=NA,add=TRUE)
plot(Chip_Bas_aea,color="black",lwd=2,fill=NA,add=TRUE)
plot(Minn_Bas_aea,color="black",lwd=2,fill=NA,add=TRUE)
plot(Bass_Bas_aea,color="black",lwd=2,fill=NA,add=TRUE)
plot(Como_Bas_aea,color="black",lwd=2,fill=NA,add=TRUE)
plot(Flam_Bas_aea,color="black",lwd=2,fill=NA,add=TRUE)
plot(Red_Bas_aea,color="black",lwd=2,fill=NA,add=TRUE)
plot(Shin_Bas_aea,color="black",lwd=2,fill=NA,add=TRUE)
plot(Trout_Bas_aea,color="black",lwd=2,fill=NA,add=TRUE)
plot(coordinates_aes) # This is where I'm running into the problem of coordinates not plotting on top of raster map
dev.off()'''
```

Comment: What happens when you add `add = TRUE` to the command for when you plot the coordinates?

Comment: That worked! Much simpler of a solution than I thought it would need haha... Thanks!